# Re-use xml gradient in other xml drawable

Tags: android, xml, gradient, drawable, shapes

I have a gradient defined in `bg_gradient.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="315"/>
</shape>
```

now I'd like to create a drawable xml which is supposed to be a circle filled with this gradient.
This is what I have so far:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <size android:height="@dimen/size_update_indicator"
        android:width="@dimen/size_update_indicator">
    </size>
    <gradient /* somehow I need to refer to bg_gradient here*/ ... />
</shape>
```

Is there a way I can refer to the existing gradient instead of just copy pasting it?

Comment: I don't think it could be possible in xml.

Comment: You can use `layer-list`.